# MySQL column organization

Tags: mysql, code-organization

My web application allows a user to define from **1 up to 30 emails** (could be anything else).
Which of these options is best?

1) ...store the data inside only one column using a separator, like this:

- **[COLUMN emails]** peter@example.com,mary@example.com,john@example.com

Structure:

```
emails VARCHAR(1829)
```

2) ...or save the data using distinct columns, like this:

- **[COLUMN email1]** peter@example.com
- **[COLUMN email2]** mary@example.com
- **[COLUMN email3]** john@example.com
- [...]

Structure:

```
email1 VARCHAR(60)
email2 VARCHAR(60)
email3 VARCHAR(60)
[...]
email30 VARCHAR(60)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you are going to use the data and how fixed the amount of 30 is. If it is an advantage to quickly query for the 3rd address or filter using WHERE clauses and such: use distinct fields; otherwise it might not be worth the effort of creating the columns.

Having the data in a database still has the advantage of concurrent access by several users.

Answer (score 1):

Number two is the better option, without question.  If you do the first one (comma separated), then it negates the advantages of using a RDBMS (you can't run an efficient query on your emails in that case, so it may as well be a flat file).

Comment: I would disagree strongly that number two is a good option, and maybe not even a better option than number one. From an application design perspective, and perhaps even from a performance perspective, checking 30 different columns for a value is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

number 2 is better than number one.

**However**, you should consider another option of getting a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) structure where you have a separate emails table with a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to your user record. This would allow you to define an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) if you wanted to search by email to find a user and place a [constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_constraints#Constraints) ensuring no duplicate emails are registered - if you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one is a very good option.

Option 1 is a poor idea because it makes looking a user up by email a complex, inefficient task. You are effectively required to perform a full text search on the email field in the user record to find one email.

Option 2 is really a WORSE idea, IMO, because it makes any surrounding code a huge pain to write. Suppose, again, that you need to look up all users who have a value X. You now need to enumerate 30 columns and check each one to see if that value exists. Painful!

Storing data in this manner -- 1-or-more of some element of data -- is very common in database design, and as Adam has previously mentioned, is best solved in MOST cases by using a normalized data structure.

A correct table structure, written in MySQL since this was tagged as such, might look like:

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
 user_id int auto_increment,
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Emails table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_email (
 user_id int,
 email char(60) not null default '',
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The `FOREIGN KEY` statement is optional -- the design will work without it, however, that line causes the database to force the relationship. For example, if you attempt to insert a record into `user_email` with a `user_id` of 10, there MUST be a corresponding `user` record with a `user_id` of 10, or the query will fail. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` tells the database that if you delete a record from the `user` table, all `user_email` records associated with it will also be deleted (you may or may not want this behavior).

This design of course also means that you need to perform a join when you retrieve a user record. A query like this:

```
 SELECT user.user_id, user_email.email FROM user LEFT JOIN user_email ON user.user_id = user_email.user_id WHERE <your where clause>;
```

Will return one row for EACH user_email address stored in the system. If you have 5 users and each user has 5 email addresses, the above query will return 25 rows.

Depending on your application, you may want to get one row per user but still have access to all the emails. In that case you might try an aggregate function like `GROUP_CONCAT` which will return a single row per user, with a comma-delimited list of emails belonging to that user:

```
 SELECT user.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_email.email) AS user_emails FROM user LEFT JOIN user_email ON user.user_id = user_email.user_id WHERE <your where clause> GROUP BY user.user_id;
```

Again, depending on your application, you may want to add an index to the email column.

Finally, there ARE some situations where you do not want a normalized database design, and a single-column design with delimited text might be more appropriate, although those situations are few and far between. For most normal applications, this type of normalized design is the way to go and will help it perform and scale better.